# cron_schedule does not update to "running" causing same job to restart repeatedly

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-cron

Magento (1.9.2.1) does not appear to be setting any of the cron jobs as "running". This is causing issues where a long-running process is being restarted repeatedly every five minutes - the below job has had the `executed_at` field updated three times - at 10:35, 10:40 and 10:45.

With Magento setting the status as "running" this is not an issue as Magento will ignore it during the next run of the cron, however because the status is not updated this long-running job is started multiple times and times-out with the message "Too late for the schedule", which I understand as meaning the cron job has exceeded it's 15 minute execution time.

```
| schedule_id | job_code        | status  | created_at          | scheduled_at        | executed_at         | finished_at |
+-------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| 25494       | my_cron_request | pending | 2020-07-06 10:35:19 | 2020-07-06 10:35:00 | 2020-07-06 10:45:15 | NULL        |
```

So, my question is:

#### How do I get Magento 1.9 to mark a cron job as "running" and to ignore "running" jobs on subsequent cron calls?

#### update:

The code to mark a cron job as running is broken in 1.9.2.1. I had to update it to 1.9.3.0:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Schedule.php
```

From:

```
public function tryLockJob($oldStatus = self::STATUS_PENDING)
{
    return $this->_getResource()->trySetJobStatusAtomic($this->getId(), self::STATUS_RUNNING, $oldStatus);
}
```

to

```
public function tryLockJob($oldStatus = self::STATUS_PENDING)
{
    $result = $this->_getResource()->trySetJobStatusAtomic($this->getId(), self::STATUS_RUNNING, $oldStatus);
    if ($result) {
        $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_RUNNING);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This change now records a cron job as "running" after it's started, but the scheduler does not exclude the job_code when searching for "pending" jobs. This is leading to jobs being started over and over:

```
| schedule_id | job_code        | status  | created_at          | scheduled_at        | executed_at         | finished_at |
+-------------+-----------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+
| 25664       | my_cron_request | running | 2020-07-06 12:20:47 | 2020-07-06 12:20:00 | 2020-07-06 12:25:15 | NULL        |
| 25665       | my_cron_request | running | 2020-07-06 12:20:47 | 2020-07-06 12:21:00 | 2020-07-06 12:35:17 | NULL        |
| 25670       | my_cron_request | running | 2020-07-06 12:20:47 | 2020-07-06 12:26:00 | 2020-07-06 12:40:23 | NULL        |
| 25675       | my_cron_request | running | 2020-07-06 12:20:47 | 2020-07-06 12:31:00 | 2020-07-06 12:45:16 | NULL        |
| 25680       | my_cron_request | running | 2020-07-06 12:20:47 | 2020-07-06 12:36:00 | 2020-07-06 12:50:22 | NULL        |
```

For context, the first job above has been running for over 30 minutes.

#### How to ignore "running" jobs on subsequent cron calls?